Issue Updating Tenant's Primary Contact Email via Deep Security API
I'm using the Deep Security API to update a tenant's primary contact email address. Here's the curl command I'm using:
curl -X POST https://dsm-url:4119/api/tenants/16 \
-H "api-secret-key: $APIKEY" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-H "api-version: v1" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"primaryContacts":[{"emailAddress":"no-reply@domain.com"}]}'

16 is the tenant ID for which I want to change the email address.
The server returns an HTTP 200 response, indicating success, but the email address remains unchanged.
I'm following the documentation text.
What might I be missing in this curl command? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Nothing in that "Modify a Tenant" endpoint's documentation indicates it accepts a primaryContacts value for modification. It appears to take an administrator value with a primaryContact boolean. You may want the modify an administrator endpoint instead.
